# Debug mode for Faust worker in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, faust

I'm trying to run faust worker (https://faust.readthedocs.io) in debug mode. At this monent I did this:

[image]

As you can see this is not actual debug. I expect this:

[image]

Can you say what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a Python run config like this to properly use debugging in PyCharm:

[image]

The file (in this case toy_example.py) should provide an entrypoint:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Application getting started")
    app.main()
```

Comment: This will not work, Faust requires the use of aiomonitor for debugging.

Comment: Have you tried it? Worked fine for me while testing with pytest!